# Sub routing in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

Is there a way by which one can map different controllers to urls that are related to each other, specifically when one is a sub resource of the other?

To be more specific, here's an example:

1. I have 2 types of resources: `jobs` and `articles`. A `job` contains multiple `articles`. Despite their relationship, I want to handle the actual code related to each in separate files. As such I have:

`helpers/job_api.rb` and

`helpers/article_api.rb`

They each extend SinatraBase like so:

```rb
class ArticleAPI < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Async

  get '/list' do
  #...
  end
end
```

What I want now is to map all url requests that belong to jobs only to the `JobAPI` and the ones that belong to articles (but still are associated with a single job at all times to the `ArticleAPI`.

My `config.ru` looks like this:

$LOAD_PATH << '.'
    require 'server'

```
map "/" do
  run Sinatra::Application
end

map "/job" do
  run JobAPI
end

map "/job/:job_id/article" do
  run ArticleAPI
end
```

But that doesn't work when I try to go to the url `/job/12/article/list`.

Anyone know if there's a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code executing in your `config.ru` file is for [Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack) which does **not** have the same routing syntax as [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes) does. Meaning that this code:

```
map "/job/:job_id/article" do
  run ArticleAPI
end
```

Probably won't work inside of the `config.ru` because Rack doesn't handle parameters in the paths, the way Sinatra does.